# I am unable to iterate between two json in golang?

Tags: go

When I am calling an endpoint point getting below two json.
In response, I need to send one json response. 
In Json1 `value` is empty and need to get the value from Json2.

I am unable to get attributes with in 
LayoutSections

*Json:1*

```
{

    "Name": "VisitDoctorLayout",
    "Kind": "Visit",
    "layoutsections": [
        {
            "label": "AccountInformation",
            "style": "TwoColumnsTopToBottom",
            "layoutcolumns": [
                {
                    "layoutitems": [
                        {
                            "behavior": "edit",
                            "name": "firstname",
                            "type": "string",
                            "label": "first Name",
                            "value": ""
                        },
                        {
                            "behavior": "Required",
                            "name": "lastname",
                            "type": "string",
                            "label": "Last Name",
                            "value": ""
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Json:2

```
{"firstname":"ABC",
"lastname":"EFZ"
}
```

My sruct is something like below

```
type Layout struct {
    ID             string           `json:"ID"`
    Name           string           `json:"name"`
    Kind           string           `json:"kind"`
    Namespace      string           `json:"namespace"`
    LayoutSections []LayoutSections `json:"layoutsections"`
}
type LayoutSections struct {
    Label         string          `json:"label"`
    Style         string          `json:"style"`
    LayoutColumns []LayoutColumns `json:"layoutcolumns"`
}

type LayoutColumns struct {
    LayoutItems []LayoutItems `json:"layoutitems"`
}
type LayoutItems struct {
    Behavior string `json:"behavior"`
    Name     string `json:"name"`
    Type     string `json:"type"`
    Label    string `json:"label"`
    Value    string `json:"value"`
}
```

Comment: You have typos: `"LayoutColumns" != "layoutcolumns"` and `"layoutSections" != "layoutsections"`

Comment: Also, the text under "Json:2" in the question isn't valid JSON; maybe you meant `{"x":"y","z":"a"}` but you have `,` instead of `:`. If none of our comments so far help you solve it, your current parsing code and expected and actual results may help folks help you.

Comment: I have changed but still getting same problem

Comment: @NagarajaSV: Your "Json:1" example works just fine, so you need to show an the actual code in question. I have no idea what you are trying to do with "Json:2".

Comment: @JimB Right now in json1 I have empty value attribute and I am trying replace those empty values with ABC and EFZ

Comment: I'm still unsure what it means to "iterate between two json". `Json:2` is an object, and the only "value" field you have defined is a string -- are you trying to encode the Json:2 value again as a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure If I got your request right but here's how I "mapped" the data from `Json2` to `Json1`.

```
// Added this for the inserter json (Json2)
type Inserter struct {
    FirstName string `json:"firstname"`
    LastName  string `json:"lastname"`
}

var dat Layout
var ins Inserter

func main() {
    if err := json.Unmarshal(json1, &dat); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    if err := json.Unmarshal(json2, &ins); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    for sk, sec := range dat.LayoutSections {
        for ck, col := range sec.LayoutColumns {
            for ik, item := range col.LayoutItems {
                itemPointer := &dat.LayoutSections[sk].LayoutColumns[ck].LayoutItems[ik]

                switch item.Name {
                case "firstname":
                    // Setting the FirstName value:
                    itemPointer.Value = ins.FirstName
                case "lastname":
                    // Setting the LastName value:
                    itemPointer.Value = ins.LastName
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### Explanation:

Basically you can just dig into the:
`Layout` > `LayoutSections` > `LayoutColumns` > `LayoutItems`

Then check for the items you want to change, in our case `firstname` & `lastname`. And finally just set their `Value` to what the `Inserter` json (Json2) contains.

---

And here's the working **[Example](https://repl.it/@mihailo_misic/MappingJsonData)** with all the details.

Comment: Thank you, Great!